# What is the most concise way to define responsive, 'art-directed', retina-supported images?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, picturefill

When wanting to serve the most appropriate image to a users device, the list of potential resources can grow pretty quickly across sizes/ratios/pixel-densities etc.

Using [picturefill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/) we can use multiple `srcset` attributes to target specific assets to given rules. An example I'm currently working on looks something like this:

```
<picture>
  <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
  <source srcset="http://dummyimage.com/360x583/707070" media="(min-width: 1200px)">
  <source srcset="http://dummyimage.com/293x476/707070, http://dummyimage.com/586x952/707070 2x" media="(min-width: 992px)">
  <source srcset="http://dummyimage.com/720x455/707070" media="(min-width: 768px)">
  <source srcset="http://dummyimage.com/330x209/707070, http://dummyimage.com/660x418/707070 2x">
  <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
  <img srcset="http://dummyimage.com/330x209/707070" alt="Item Image">
</picture>
```

This is certainly not [terrible](http://www.xanthir.com/b4Su0), but it's starting to feel pretty verbose again. There are 6 different sources specified for the same image, and that's only including 2 'double density' retina images. We're also required to provide a pretty spurious `<video>` tag to avoid IE9 woes.

Should we be providing double density resources for all image dimensions, or make an explicit assumption that 2x image displays are only available at certain screen resolutions (which seems like a pretty big assumption).

Similarly, should we be providing 3x image resolutions for any/all of our resources?

If the answer to either of these were yes, we can see that for a very standard set of target device widths (these are Bootstraps `xs`, `sm`, `md` and `lg` values), we might well end up having to provide 8 or even 12 resources per 'picture'.

So, is this simply the best current state-of-play? (picturefill definitely does help). Or is trying to specify a specific resource for every eventuality over-engineering the problem?

**Update**
For more recent approaches, follow the progress on [Responsive Images Community Group](https://responsiveimages.org/)

Comment: Is there a reason you do do not try to choose and deliver the appropriate image on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

I was just reading a pretty awesome article last night on the subject by Jason Grigsby.
http://blog.cloudfour.com/dont-use-picture-most-of-the-time/

```
<img src="cat_500px.jpg"
    srcset="cat_750px.jpg 1.5x, cat_1000px.jpg 2x"
    width="500px" alt="lolcat">
```

Another perhaps more technical article here:
https://dev.opera.com/articles/native-responsive-images/

Edit
Also important, where it can actually be usefull
http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset